# jQuery file upload not resizing images anymore

Tags: jquery-plugins, file-upload, image-resizing

I use jQuery file upload in my project since three months to upload and resize image files. Everything was working fine until last week. The plugin doesn't resize the images anymore (latest google chrome and latest firefox).

I'm using the same basic configuration on this page https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Does someone has the same issue and maybe a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: you have to do it on your own I suppose.Can you say me what server side are you using?If it is in asp.net I can help you.

Comment: No, the plugin is supposed to resize the image before sending it so it's faster to upload. Everything was working fine before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is what I'm doing at present is:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'Upload.ashx,
      done: function (e, data) {
      $("#page_navigation").show();
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $('#placeholderforimages').append("<img style='height:48px;width:65px;' src='yourimagepath'>");
            }
 });
```

UPDATE:

Here is the wiki [options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) you need to make an array and need to declare in that

```
[
    {
        action: 'load',
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
        maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
    },
    {
        action: 'resize',
        maxWidth: 1920,
        maxHeight: 1200,
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 600
    },
    {
        action: 'save'
    }
],
```

Comment: Your code is the solution but why did it work before without theses options ? Anyway thanks !

Comment: It was exactly the same code as yours without the "process" parameters.

Comment: Maybe but everything is fine now. Thanks again :)

Comment: where do you add these options?

Comment: @elibyy Look at Devin Crossman's answer. He shows where to add it.

Answer (score 16):

I couldn't get client side image resizing to work and I discovered it was because I had overridden the add method and didn't include code to do the image resizing that was in the original method. I'll post my solution in hopes that it helps save someone some frustration.

```
<form action="/path/to/uploadHandler" id="multiple-image-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input name="files" multiple="multiple" id="files" type="file">
</form>

<div id="file-upload-progress">
    <div id="upload-progress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#multiple-image-upload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        process:[
            {
                action: 'load',
                fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
                maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
            },
            {
                action: 'resize',
                maxWidth: 1920,
                maxHeight: 1200,
                minWidth: 800,
                minHeight: 600
            },
            {
                action: 'save'
            }
        ],
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading '+data.files[0].name+'...').appendTo("#file-upload-progress");
            var $this = $(this);
            data.process(function () {
                return $this.fileupload('process', data);
            }).done(function() {
                data.submit();
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.html('<img src="'+data.result.files[0].thumbnailUrl+'" alt="'+data.result.files[0].name+'" />');
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#upload-progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            ).text(
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: tks, I had the same issue, I was calling .submit in the custom add, but not calling process.

fwiw, I didn't need to add a custom process: parameter, once I changed my code from 
    data.submit()
to
    .process(function () {
            return fileUploader.fileupload('process', data);
     })
     .done(function () { data.submit()}

it worked, and observed the imageMaxHeight:xyz etc parameters as outlined in the official howto (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing).

Comment: Thanks very much, how do I specify the preview min width/height in this?

Comment: @Mike your comment helped me to know where i was going wrong, i made same mistake as you. Thanks

Comment: My add method was callign resize twice, i had a custom hook in resize to notify of the origonal file dimensions, now with this add method overriding logic, this issue is solved.(it seems)

Comment: Hi, I currently have the same issue and this solution solved the resizing problem. However, it is only processing 1 file even if multiple uploads is enabled. Multiple uploads was working well before adding the "process" codes. Is there a separate action for multiple processing?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems too with jQuery File Upload and manage to solve it by changing the options in the file "jquery.fileupload-image.js" in the following section:

```
// The File Upload Resize plugin extends the fileupload widget
// with image resize functionality:
$.widget('blueimp.fileupload', $.blueimp.fileupload, {

    options: {
        ...
        // The maximum file size of images to load:
        loadImageMaxFileSize: 20000000, // 10MB
        // The maximum width of resized images:
        imageMaxWidth: 250,
        // The maximum height of resized images:
        imageMaxHeight: 250,
        ...
        // Disable the resize image functionality by default:
        disableImageResize: false,
        ...
    },
```

Somehow do the options put "somewhere else" (in my case, all code copied from the official tutorial from the official page) not override the default options stated/shown here.

- This could be my fault, so no offense. Anyway, if this advice can help someone else, here it is. Try it out if you like or leave it.